# C# & ASP.NET MVC 5 - execute stored procedure from button click with no return values

Tags: c#, entity-framework, stored-procedures, ssis, asp.net-mvc-5

I'm trying (I'm in need to) to create small web application to manage some ETL processes giving my users few buttons to view SQL Server data and run few SSIS Packages.

I was able to handle the website creation using a C# ASP.NET MVC CRUD tutorial [HERE](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=TlQRDKGeoOQ&t=298s) (really useful) and to show the data I need.

I then created a data model pointing to my tables and stored procedures and now I "only" need to create a basic page with a textbox to insert a parameter and a button for each stored procedure I need to run.

Each stored procedure will run an SSIS package that doesn't need to return any value for now.

EDIT: I was able to gather some more information and to modify the code like this

**Controller**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.Entity;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Net;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Mvc;
using Italist_Admin.Models;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects;

namespace Project.Controllers
{
    public class ToolsController : Controller
    {
        private ProjectEntities db = new ProjectEntities();

        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            ProjectEntities entities = new ProjectEntities();
            //return View(entities.SPU_RUNSSIS(""));
            return View();

        }
        [HttpPost]

        public ActionResult ExecExportOnly(string txtPeriod)  // to get the Student Details  
        {
            ProjectEntities entities = new ProjectEntities();

            entities.SPU_RUNSSIS(parameter);
            return View();

        }}}
```

**View**

```
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Tools";
}

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
    <title>Export Only</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div>
        @using (Html.BeginForm("ExecExportOnly", "Tools", FormMethod.Post))
        {
            <span>Period:</span> @Html.TextBox("txtPeriod")
            <input type="submit" value="Run Export" />
        }
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

**Model**

```
  public virtual int SPU_RUNSSIS(string parameter)
    {
        var periodParameter = period != null ?
            new ObjectParameter("parameter", parameter) :
            new ObjectParameter("parameter", typeof(string));

        ((IObjectContextAdapter)this).ObjectContext.CommandTimeout = 300;
        return ((IObjectContextAdapter)this).ObjectContext.ExecuteFunction("SPU_RUNSSIS", parameterParameter);

    }
```

I added a timeout in the model because on execution, after 30 seconds it was failing due to timeout.

Running this code, the packaged fails (*SqlException: The package failed. Check the SSIS catalog logs for more information*) after about 30 seconds anyway and AT THE END of the 30 seconds I see in the SQL Trace the following message

*RPC:Completed - exec [dbo].[SPU_RUNSSIS] @parameter='parametervalue'*

If I manually run the code above, it works.

I'm almost there but it seems I can't find the correct way to trigger the execution of the stored procedure at some point.

Thanks in advance for any suggestion

Comment: It seems that the package did execute according to the error message: **SqlException: The package failed. Check the SSIS catalog logs for more information**.  What's in the ssis catalog reports for that execution?

Comment: Nothing, in fact the ssis package does not run. If I manually execute the same SQL code it starts correctly.

Comment: I'm having trouble following you.  You say running the code that package fails, but in your comments here you say it does not run.  Where is error message coming from that says the package failed?

Comment: Ok it's strange indeed. The message is returned from the vs debugger, but the ssis doesn't even starts.

Comment: Maybe check the connection details and make sure that it is running on the server that you expect it to be running on

Comment: I use the same connection in other views to show table data in web pages. I can't rule out that the function I'm using to call the stored procedure is not the best way to do it. But I've no knowledge of it, I arranged some code by doing copy and paste from different tutorials!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to circumvent the problem by firing the SSIS directly from the c# code instead of executing a stored procedure that then triggers the SSIS execution.

Maybe not the best solution, but it seems to work:

```
public ActionResult Index()
    {
        project entities = new project();
        return View();

    }
    public ActionResult ExecExportOnly(string txtPeriod)
    {
        project entities = new project();

        string targetServerName = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["targetServerName"];
        string folderName = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["folderName"];
        string projectName = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["projectName"]; 
        string SSIS_ExportOnly = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["SSIS_ExportOnly"];

        // Create a connection to the server
        string sqlConnectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["Variable1"].ConnectionString;

        SqlConnection sqlConnection = new SqlConnection(sqlConnectionString);

        // Create the Integration Services object
        IntegrationServices integrationServices = new IntegrationServices(sqlConnection);

        // Get the Integration Services catalog
        Catalog catalog = integrationServices.Catalogs["SSISDB"];

        // Get the folder
        CatalogFolder folder = catalog.Folders[folderName];

        // Get the project
        ProjectInfo project = folder.Projects[projectName];

        // Get the package
        PackageInfo package = project.Packages[SSIS_ExportOnly];

        //Set Parameters
        // Add a parameter collection for 'system' parameters (ObjectType = 50), package parameters (ObjectType = 30) and project parameters (ObjectType = 20)
        Collection<PackageInfo.ExecutionValueParameterSet> executionParameter = new Collection<PackageInfo.ExecutionValueParameterSet>();

        // Add execution parameter (value) to override the default asynchronized execution. If you leave this out the package is executed asynchronized
        //executionParameter.Add(new PackageInfo.ExecutionValueParameterSet { ObjectType = 50, ParameterName = "SYNCHRONIZED", ParameterValue = 1 });

        // Add execution parameter (value) to override the default logging level (0=None, 1=Basic, 2=Performance, 3=Verbose)
        executionParameter.Add(new PackageInfo.ExecutionValueParameterSet { ObjectType = 50, ParameterName = "LOGGING_LEVEL", ParameterValue = 3 });

        // Add a project parameter (value) to fill a project parameter
        //executionParameter.Add(new PackageInfo.ExecutionValueParameterSet { ObjectType = 20, ParameterName = "MyProjectParameter", ParameterValue = "some value" });

        // Add a project package (value) to fill a package parameter
        executionParameter.Add(new PackageInfo.ExecutionValueParameterSet { ObjectType = 30, ParameterName = "ParamPeriod", ParameterValue = txtPeriod });

        // Get the identifier of the execution to get the log
        //long executionIdentifier = package.Execute(false, null, executionParameter);

        // Run the package
        package.Execute(true, null,executionParameter);

        return View("Index");
    }
```

Thanks anyways!
R

Comment: After so many tests I discovered I falled into the double hop problem between Client - SQL Server - File Server (where I export the files with the SSIS). I managed to temporarily bypass the problem using this tutorial (http://nikolar.com/2015/03/10/creating-network-share-with-anonymous-access/)
I need to deepen the Kerberos part before destroying everything!